# How to connect Netsuite Rest Api with Pentaho Spoon Rest Client

Tags: netsuite

I trying to access data from restlet using spoon rest client but it is not working. I am creating a field in add rows named creadentials. And passing this hole string in heders of rest client.

```
Authorization: NLAuth nlauth_account=12345, nlauth_email=jsmith@ABC.com, nlauth_signature=xxxx, nlauth_role=4
```

But i am getting error as no authorization headers.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. We have to put authorization as name and

```
NLAuth nlauth_account=123, nlauth_email=abc@abc.com, nlauth_signature=password, nlauth_role=3
```

as value in add rows of spoon client and also add content-type as name and application/json as value then add all the fields in parameters. You have to add name as authorization and field authorization again name content-type field content-type. Remove default authorization username and password because we are sending it with the headers.